# STM32 IAP Boot + Two Applications

Tags: in-app-purchase, embedded, stm32

I have the following setup on my STM32F4xx

**Flash Start**

- Boot
- Reserved Area
- Application 1 Region
- Application 2 Region

**Flash End**

Boot can program to App1 and App2 regions using IAP (bluetooth).
App1 can program to Boot and App2 regions using IAP (bluetooth).
App2 can program to Boot and App1 regions using IAP (bluetooth).

This works fine, but App1 and App2 are compiled knowing in which region will be programmed.

In the link script I have to place the address where the app will be and the size of the region.

```
/* Specify the memory areas */
MEMORY
{
FLASH (rx)      : ORIGIN = FLASH_ADDRESS_APP, LENGTH = APPLICATION_LENGTH
RAM (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 192K
CCMRAM (rw)      : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 64K
}
```

Also I have to know where the ISR Table will be, in my case I have set the first region:

```
SECTIONS
{
  /* The startup code goes first into FLASH */
  .isr_vector :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    KEEP(*(.isr_vector)) /* Startup code */
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH
```

So I have set SCB->VTOR = FLASH_ADDRESS_APP

Is there a way to compile in the same way two applications without knowing in which region will be?

Comment: **P**osition **I**ndipendet **C**ode is the way. [-fPIC option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html) if you are using gcc